# IllegalStateException when upgrading to Spring Boot 2.1.7

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, tomcat9

I have a Spring Boot application, which is running fine and has with the following setup

- Spring Webflux + Tomcat
- Spring Actuator as dependency.
- Spring Boot 2.1.2
- Java 1.8.0_212
- Gradle 5.1 build

However when I update to Spring Boot 2.1.7 & Spring 5.1.9 the application fails to start.
This is the error in the logs

```
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling [asyncOperation()] is not valid for a request with Async state [COMPLETING]**
```

This is the stack trace

```
*org.apache.coyote.AsyncStateMachine.asyncOperation(AsyncStateMachine.java:269) 
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.dispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:203)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)*
```

What could be the issue ?

Comment: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51630   Perhaps you are using too old of a JDK?

Comment: The project is using Java 1.8. Updated my question.